# Firebase 'set' function deletes entire node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase Cloud functions to run a few trigger based functions.

My database looks like this

```
users{
     userId{
            dataSets{
               dataSet1 { //data } 
               dataSet2 { //data }
            }
            weeklyTriggers { 
                 dataSet1{
                    weekNo{
                       //updates
                    }
                 }
            }
      }
}
```

I'm using the `onWrite` function as a trigger on a specific node:

```
exports.doSome = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/dataSets/{dataSetNo}').onWrite(
async (change, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  const dataSetNo = context.params.dataSetNo;
  const weekNo = getWeekNo(); //is a custom function works fine
  var databaseRef = admin.database().ref('users');
  databaseRef.child(userId).child('weeklyTriggers').child(dataSetNo).child(weekNo).set({
    data: 'Some Data'
  });
});
```

The problem I'm running into is, when I do an update for `dataSet1` it sets the value, but, when I set the value for `dataSet2`, it deletes the entire node `weeklyTriggers` and then creates `weeklyTriggers/dataSet2/30/`

How do I ensure that `weeklyTriggers` doesn't get deleted?

edit:

Updated code

```
exports.doSome = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/dataSets/{dataSetNo}').onWrite(
 async (change, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  const yearNo = context.params.yearNo;
  const weekNo = getWeekNo();
  var ref = change.after.ref.root.child('users');
  var dataPath = `${userId}/weeklyTriggers/${dataSetNo}/${weekNo}/data`;

  var foo={};
  foo[dataPath] = "Some data";

  return ref.update(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `set()` on a location, all data at that location will be replaced by the data you provide in the call. If you only want to update certain properties under the location, use `update()`.

For example:

```
databaseRef.child(userId).child('weeklyTriggers').child(dataSetNo).child(weekNo).update({
  data: 'Some Data'
});
```

You can provide paths to `update` to update properties deeper in the JSON. So the above could also be done with:

```
databaseRef.update({
  `${userId}/weeklyTriggers/${dataSetNo}/${weekNo}/data`: 'Some Data'
});
```

Comment: Hey Frank, I tried out your suggestion. It still deletes the node `weeklyTriggers` and recreates it.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud function should return a promise, otherwise it can be terminated before the operation is successfully finished, and this can cause unexpected results. Try adding return to your set() operation.

```
return databaseRef.child(userId).child('weeklyTriggers').child(dataSetNo).child(weekNo).set({
    data: 'Some Data'
  });
```

Or you can also add await, but its quite useless in this situation

Comment: Thanks Teempy. I tried that out, still deletes and recreates the node. I've updated the post with my code.

Comment: Its strange. I tried to represent the same situation in my project and simplified it a bit: https://i.imgur.com/7D9IvFj.jpg, everything works as expected, i can write to the dataset and the function only adds a new value without deleting anything. Does the function behave differently in different situations? Are there any messages in the function log?

Comment: That is strange. No, there are no messages in the function log. Let me double check the front end to see if there's anything going on there that could trigger this. Thank you for taking the trouble to put that together!